# Manually update an Auto update time stamp column

Tags: sql, plsql, timestamp

I want to update a timestamp column manually which is auto updated when we insert a row or update. When i update the table through pl/sql stored procedure, i want to keep the old time stamp value itself. Is this Psooible?

Comment: Its useful to explain what you have tried so far, could you add that to your question please?

Comment: We have one table with colums LST_MAINT_TS which has Two trigers accociated with it. Whenever a row is inserted or updated, LST_MAINT_TS will have CURRENT TS value. This is done through triigers. Now we are writing a new PL/SQL stored procedure to update this table rows. Whenever we update it from our stored proceudre LST_MAINT_TS is updated with CURRENT TS.But we want to skip this update and maintain the previous value of LST_MAINT_TS itself.I tried to manually update the column LST_MAINT_TS but it still takes the CURRENT TS because of Trigger.How to prevent this trigger from being exceuted?

Comment: I have tried the fllowing commands in my stored procedure. "DISABLE TRIGGER trigger name ON table name;", "ALTER TABLE table name DISABLE TRIGGER trigger name;", "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER trigger name DISABLE';", " DISABLE trigger name:". But all of the above resulted in either syntax error or run time error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you want to update the timestamp column (I want to update a timestamp column manually) or no (i want to keep the old time stamp value itself) when the row is modified.

However it is possible for the timestamp value to be updated automatically whenever you insert a new row by using "INSERT ON" trigger.

If you want the timestamp value to be updated whenever record is updated, you can use "UPDATE ON" trigger.